# Type 'Observable<{}[]>' is not assignable to type 'AngularFireList<any>'

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.joshmorony.com/building-a-crud-ionic-2-application-with-firebase-angularfire/) about using AngularFire2.

> *Type 'Observable<{}[]>' is not assignable to type 'AngularFireList'.
>     Property 'query' is missing in type 'Observable<{}[]>'.*

Where in fact after seeing some reference base from [this](https://alligator.io/angular/firebase-crud-operations/). Also tried to do the same here in the [repo](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md#50) but still unlucky not to find the answer

Code below:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-graph-sensor',
  templateUrl: 'graph-sensor.html',
})
export class GraphSensorPage {
  sensorData: AngularFireList<any[]>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public firedb: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.sensorData = firedb.list('/reading').valueChanges();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(firedb.list('/reading').valueChanges()));
  }
```

Comment: What happens if you remove `.valueChanges()`?

Comment: returns a object with a link to my firebase

Comment: something like {"query" : "to my firebase url" } with valuechanges it returns an observable object

Answer (score 0):

`valueChanges` is an `Observable` so you won't get the `JSON` data back without subscribing to it. I assume you're wanting to see the data?

Try running;

```
 this.sensorData: any[];


 firedb.list('/reading').valueChanges()
   .subscribe(sensorData => {
     this.sensorData = sensorData;
   });
```

Also you shouldn't be running this logic in your `constructor`. Instead you should have in in `ngOnInit`. When subscribing you are responsible for unsubscribing. An easy pattern is to unsubscribe on `ngOnDestroy`.

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-graph-sensor',
  templateUrl: 'graph-sensor.html',
})
export class GraphSensorPage implements OnInit {
  sensorData$: Subscription;
  sensorData: any[];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public firedb: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sensorData$ = firedb.list('/reading').valueChanges()
      .subscribe(sensorData => {
        this.sensorData = sensorData;
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sensorData$.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry for the late response i got this error "polyfills.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function" i dont know why it happens